# I have a web app hosted on PythonAnywhere and it seems to be working fine on Chrome in Windows but on my phone not all the features are displayed

Tags: django, bootstrap-5, pythonanywhere

I have hosted a Django application on PythonAnywhere at anavenger9.pythonanywhere.com. The application works the way it should on my laptop but when I go to the site on my phone the navigation bars I created using Bootstrap5 are missing. What should I do?

I tried disabling Forced https but it did not work.